# How to combine various certificates into single .pem

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, consolidation

I've just finished reading over this [great thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file) explaining the different SSL formats.

Now I'm essentially looking for the opposite of [How to split a PEM file](https://serverfault.com/questions/391396/how-to-split-a-pem-file)

There's 4 files I want to consolidate, originally created for Apache, I'm looking at files specified by

- SSLCertificateFile
- SSLCertificateKeyFile
- SSLCertificateChainFile
- SSLCACertificateFile

What I'm mostly curious about is the order of the files in the consolidated dereivative, is that important?  EG. if I were to just `cat` them together in the order they appear above, into a *.pem*, would it be valid, or should they be ordered a specific way?

FYI, I'm doing this for sake of using these certs as a combined single *.pem* in [SimpleSAMLphp](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/configure-simplesaml-1.3-sp-and-shibboleth-2.1-idp/start).

Comment: The order should be private key, intermediate certs, your certificate.

Comment: What about the CA, isn't that the root of the chain, and therefore it would go after the chain in the consolidated file?  Or can it be omitted entirely?

Comment: [Sounds like it's optional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899983/difference-between-sslcacertificatefile-and-sslcertificatechainfile), I'll roll w/o it for now.

Comment: `SSLCACertificateFile` is completely unrelated to the other directives as it's used for client authentication.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The order does matter, according to [RFC 4346](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-7.4.2).

Here is a quote directly taken from the RFC:

```
  certificate_list
    This is a sequence (chain) of X.509v3 certificates.  The sender's
    certificate must come first in the list.  Each following
    certificate must directly certify the one preceding it.  Because
    certificate validation requires that root keys be distributed
    independently, the self-signed certificate that specifies the root
    certificate authority may optionally be omitted from the chain,
    under the assumption that the remote end must already possess it
    in order to validate it in any case.
```

Based on this information, the server certificate should come first, followed by any intermediate certs, and finally the root trusted authority certificate (if self-signed). I could not find any information on the private key, but I think that should not matter because a private key in pem is easy to identify as it starts and ends with the text below, which has the keyword `PRIVATE` in it.

```
 -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: cat site.crt root.crt site.key > site.pem

Comment: Please do not be mistaken - the information from the RFC does not answer the question. **The RFC talks about the TLS protocol, not about the PEM format for storing certificates in a file.**

Comment: @pabouk Can you elaborate on that? I always thought the order was important as defined in this answer. _BUT_, I just recently dumped all the certs in my PFX file to a PEM file using openssl and the order of the bundle was as follows: server, Root CA, Intermediate CA. Furthermore, verifying this bundle succeeded with the following command!: `openssl verify -show_chain -no-CAfile -no-CApath -untrusted <( { openssl x509 >/dev/nul; cat; } < server.crt ) <(openssl x509 < server.crt)`. So, I'm a little confused and want to make sure I understand this correctly. Thanks!

Comment: @pabouk (Follow on from previous comment...) And perhaps what I'm seeing is because of _exactly_ what you say, the RFC is about the _TLS protocol_ while PEM is just a (file) format. I would expect `openssl` to correctly extract a valid PEM-formatted certificate bundle from a PKCS12 (PFX) file. (And, yes, my bundle does not need to have the Root CA cert in it because we add our internal CA to all of our machine's certificate store, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: Interesting, I just did my own test. Note that when I said my bundle "passed verification", that's because I _actually didn't_ include the `-no-CAfile -noCApath` parameters originally, so OpenSSL used the Root CA in my computer's store. So, that makes sense. But, verifying that bundle using `no-CAfile -noCApath -untrusted ...` as shown above _actually FAILS_ verification--is it should. I claimed all certificates after the endpoint entity certificate were _untrusted_. So it would seem that in the PEM file, order does not matter, but that the endpoint entity cert _should_ come first. (cont'd)

Comment: After the endpoint entity certificate, the order doesn't matter. _If_ the private key were to be included in the bundle, I'm unsure of whether it's placement matters in the file. But, since I don't require the private key in the bundle, I'm not overly concerned with that right now.

Hopefully someone can verify that my understanding is correct.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight Unfortunately I cannot give you more details and thank you for providing results of your tests. --- I just wanted to point out that the answer is wrong in the sense that it assumes that RFC 4346 (TLS 1.1) says something about the PEM file format.

Comment: Thanks @pabouk, I agree with you, even more so after conducting additional research. It seems it really doesn't matter what order the certificates are in inside the bundle. Even the server cert doesn't appear to _have_ to appear first--it just does because it makes using the bundle with OpenSSL _much_ easier.

Comment: I did some more testing. So, along with this other SF Q&A answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1068283/217313) and my comments on it, I'm convinced that the order of certificates in a PEM file is not important. The ordering in the file can, however, make it really easy or really hard to work with using OpenSSL. But that's a different question altogether! So, yes, this question is factually incorrect in its assertions and is really talking about the TLS protocol and not the PEM file, which is just a data container as @pabouk asserts. I'm only not downvoting because of my low rep :(.

Answer (score 24):

Here is the command to combine using `cat`

```
cat first_cert.pem second_cert.pem > combined_cert.pem
```

Comment: It's an answer how to concatenate any two certs, but but not how to consolidate/concatenate certs for Apache.

Comment: This is not really to answer the question, the accepted answer is good enough. I just provide additional informations on how to concatenate, as the original poster talked about using cat, I thought it might help others.

Comment: Your answer does not indicate *what order* the files should be concatenated in (you just have "first_cert.pem" and "second_cert.pem"). The correct answer would be `cat my_site.pem ca_chain.pem my_site.key > combined_cert.pem`

Comment: @DoktorJ Most of the reliable sources say that the private key comes first, not last in the combined PEM file.

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong I'd be less inclined to think that would matter.  The order of certificates is important because it gets used in TLS handshake: "here's my certificate, my certificate is signed by this, this is signed by that, ...".  The private key does not get relayed in the protocol so won't influence the order of anything in the handshake.