# openssl certificate chain lost when converting from pem to der

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509

I have a cetificate chain in .pem format from Letsencrypt, called fullchain.pem

It has 2 certificates in the chain:

```
keytool -printcert -v -file fullchain.pem |grep "Certificate fingerprints" |wc -l
2
```

When I convert it to .der using

```
openssl x509 -in fullchain.pem -out cert.der -outform DER
```

it only exports the last one

```
keytool -printcert -v -file cert.der |grep "Certificate fingerprints" |wc -l
1
```

is this a bug in openssl? Am I missing a param?

Comment: `openssl x509` processes only the first cert in the input file and ignores any additional ones. You need to split 'fullchain' up and process each cert separately. See https://serverfault.com/questions/391396/how-to-split-a-pem-file and https://serverfault.com/questions/590870/how-to-view-all-ssl-certificates-in-a-bundle

Comment: Thanks, it clarified the issue. I wonder why openssl doesn't emit any warnings about this.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot have DER encoded chains by concatenating them the way you can with PEM format.

A chain in a *binary* format would be in PKCS#7 format.  To convert a PEM chain to PKCS#7, use:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile fullchain.pem -out fullchain.p7b
```

Then, to see the contents:

```
openssl pkcs7 -in fullchain.p7b -print_certs -noout
```

Add `-text` to see all the certificate details.

If the input PEM file also contained a private key a better format would be PKCS#12 as this format can be secured with a passphrase.

Comment: Great! This also solves it.

Comment: Btw, they say it is actually possible to concatenate .der certificates to import them later, see this Java snippet https://gist.github.com/spicydog/84fa0e74d8524fba1fbb

Comment: @ArticIceJuice - I think you may well be correct :-) [generateCertificates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html#generateCertificates(java.io.InputStream)) accepts a stream of DER encoded certs.  As I can't find a standard that defines certificate chains, this may well be implementation specific.